# sphinx filter by distinct field

Tags: php, mysql, centos, sphinx

I use coreseek 4.1 on centos6.5. coreseek config file like that:

`sql_query = select id,username,ordersn,addtime from order where ispay=1;`

I what to select users who's order num > 10 between some time.

That's my code:

```
$s = new SphinxClient;
$s->setServer("localhost", 9312);
$s->setArrayResult(true);
$s->SetGroupDistinct("ordersn");
$s->SetGroupBy("username",SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR);
$s->SetFilterRange("@distinct", 10, 999999);
$result = $s->query('', 'my_index');
```

But it return null.when i remove `$s->SetFilterRange("@distinct", 10, 999999);` it return 1261 total_found,some resut like that:

```
       [18] => Array
            (
                [id] => 238041
                [weight] => 1
                [attrs] => Array
                    (
                        [ordersn] => 0
                        [username] => 0
                        [addtime] => 1448959834
                        [@groupby] => 8980267602450089129
                        [@count] => 20
                        [@distinct] => 28
                    )

            )
```

It meas that there is someone's ordernum > 10.But how cound i find them by sphinx(coreseek)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible in SphinxQL:

```
SELECT *,COUNT(DISTINCT ordersn) AS orders FROM my_index GROUP BY user HAVING orders >= 10
```

which has a 'HAVING' clause, since 2.2.1-beta. (I think coreseek 5 is based on?)

As far as I am aware this has never been added to the SphinxAPI.

Comment: For some reason,i can't count the orders in SphinxQL.It's need to  join many tables,and it will changes by the addtime.So i must count orders by sphinxAPI and filter with addtime. Anyway,many TKS!

Comment: figure out that 'some reason'. You should be able to do everything you did in sphinxQL, as you do via the API. If you can count orders via the API, you can via SphinxQL too. They are just a 'communication' medium to the same query engine.